# Query SQL to SOQL

Tags: soql, force.com, force.com-explorer

I want write this query whith SOQL

```
Selecte User.Username, CollaborationGroup.Name,CollaborationGroup.LastModifiedDate
From User, CollaborationGroup 
Where User.Id = CollaborationGroup.OwnerID 
            AND CollaborationGroup.LastModifiedDate < 2013-04-20T14:00:00.000Z
```

thx.

Comment: whith SOQL we don't do this, i tried in Force.com Explorer but i have an error

Comment: @KhaledZero: You're likely to get voted down because your question does not show any research or attempted SOQL. Try reading some of the SOQL documentation or using Workbench first (http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html) and posting what you have tried and you'll get better responses.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to query the `CollaborationGroup` object directly:

```
Select Owner.Name, Name, LastModifiedDate 
From CollaborationGroup 
Where LastModifiedDate < 2013-04-20T14:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Thx
but i want get Username of User in the same query

Comment: @KhaledZero `Owner.Name` is the name of the owner (user).

Comment: @mastOr Username is like this "name@force.com" and it is a premary key

Comment: @KhaledZero Well, then use `Owner.Username`!

Comment: @mastOr when I use Owner.Username I have this result: http://hpics.li/dc9a067 but me I want in Owner things lik this 'name@force.com' .... and not 'Owner' for all groups
thx

Comment: You are seeing a behavior of the Force.com Explorer. I'd recommend running the query in Developer Console or Workbench instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Owner.Username, LastFeedModifiedDate, Name, OwnerId FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90
```